# How to make my button positioned:absolute in React Js

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if you are seeing this again. I realized I did not give enough information in my last post.

If you didnt see my last post I want to make my button position absolute. Below is the line in my section:

```
 <Button href={LINKS.application} external>
          Join today!
        </Button>
```

and here is the code in my button component:

```
 export type ButtonProps = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement> & {
  iconName?: SupportedIcons
  external?: boolean
  href?: string
  target?: HTMLAttributeAnchorTarget
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ children, external, iconName, disabled, href, target, ...props }) => {
  if (href)
    return (
      <Link href={href}>
        <a
          href={href}
          target={target ?? (external ? '_blank' : '_self')}
          className={`font-secondary text-xs md:text-base flex flex-row items-center gap-2 bg-white rounded-xl px-5 py-4 text-content-button font-bold hover:opacity-70 duration-300 ${
            disabled ? 'cursor-not-allowed opacity-70' : 'cursor-pointer'
          }`}
        >
          {!!iconName && <Icon iconName={iconName} />}
          <span>{children}</span>
          {external && <Icon iconName="arrow" />}
        </a>
      </Link>
    )

  return (
    <button
      {...props}
      disabled={disabled}
      className={`font-secondary text-xs md:text-base flex flex-row items-center gap-2 bg-white rounded-xl px-5 py-4 text-content-button font-bold hover:opacity-70 duration-300 ${
        disabled && 'cursor-not-allowed opacity-70'
      }`}
    >
      {!!iconName && <Icon iconName={iconName} />}
      {children}
      {external && <Icon iconName="arrow" />}
    </button>
  )
}
```

I hope this helps to see where I can add the positioning. Thanks